# What is Threshold in the Evaluate Model Module?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Notice in the image below, if I increase the value of "Threshold," the accuracy of the model seems to increase (with diminishing returns after about .62).

What does this mean and can I somehow update this value such that my model will retain this setting?

For example, I am using a boosted decision tree, but I don't see any such value for "threshold."

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/evaluate-model?redirectedfrom=MSDN

[image]

Comment: [Evaluate Model component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/component-reference/evaluate-model) and [Azure Machine Learning: Model Evaluation and Threshold Manipulation](http://breaking-bi.blogspot.com/2017/02/azure-machine-learning-model-evaluation_20.html)

Answer (score 1):

The term **Threshold** defines the line of separation between the variables before implementation of the evaluation metrics. We need to split the dataset into two different parts with different ratios.

For example, we have 9 rows in our dataset and we need to split it for training and testing purposes. Let us consider first two rows are for testing purposes and remaining are for training purposes. The **Threshold** is the **Hyperplane** the seperation line between the categories. When we need to split the data after training into categories, we need to differentiate between them with some threshold value. Based on the number of training and testing variables the threshold value will be automatically assigned by **scikit learn**.

It is true that if we increase the threshold based on the number of training variables and testing variables, the accuracy will increase. That will show impact on **precision and recall**.

Check out the [blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-threshold-in-machine-learning/) on the same, regarding the importance of threshold in decision trees.

Blog Contribution: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/